# How do I give an input to an infinitely running program?

Tags: linux, io, input

I have a python program that runs infinitely, takes an input and throws an output. I want to write a bash program that gives an input while the python script is running. So, how do I give an input to the program while the program is running ?

Comment: Your statement _"takes an input and throws an output"_ indicates that you have a way to input something into this program. You need to be more clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Currently I'm typing the input on the terminal and now I want to do that using a bash script.

Comment: I don't have any python programming experience but 1. check for existence of an input file; 2. read input from file; 3. delete file; 4. goto step-1

Comment: You may have to re-write it to let it recognize a text file as it's input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to use a named pipe:

```
# Choosing a unique, secure name for the pipe left as an exercise
PIPE=/tmp/feed-data-to-program

# Create the named pipe
mkfifo "$PIPE"
# Start the Python program in the background
myprogram <"$PIPE" &
# Now grab an open handle to write the pipe
exec 3>"$PIPE"
# And we don't need to refer to the pipe by name anymore
rm -f "$PIPE"

# Later, the shell script does other work,...
# ...possibly in a loop?
while :; do
    ...
    ...
    # Now I've got something to send to the background program
    echo foo >&3
    ...
    ...
done
```

It would be nice to avoid the need for a temporary entry in the filesystem, and I know that some shells like `zsh` provide a way to do that, but I don't know of a portable way.